# Selecting Column Slice from Cassandra using CQL

Tags: cassandra, cql3

I'm understand in Cassandra, especially cqlsh I can get a slice of columns.  I will explain in a moment.  Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE movies (
    key text PRIMARY KEY,
    boot text,
    effect text,
    foo text,
    movie text,
    starring text
);
```

and some contents:

```
key       | boot                | effect | foo  | movie         | starring
-----------+-----------------------+--------+------+---------------+----------
  starwars | Revenge of the Nerds3 |   null |  bar |     Star Wars |     null
 star trek |                  null |   null | null | into darkness |     null
```

Now, I'm to understand I can get a slice of these columns:  like, say effect, foo and movie by the following:

```
select effect..movie from movies
```

and I should get all of these columns.  However, this is what I get when I run the query:

```
Bad Request: line 1:7 no viable alternative at input 'effect'
```

Is this what I should be doing or is there another procedure or is my thinking / information incorrect?

Part of my assumption is based on what is shown in [Are CQL2 column slices and CQL3 wheres on composite keys equivalent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15269782/are-cql2-column-slices-and-cql3-wheres-on-composite-keys-equivalent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing Thrift columns with CQL3 columns.

1. What you want to accomplish is pretty easy using a list of column names in the `SELECT`:

   Select all columns:

   ```
   SELECT * from movies
   ```

   Select only specific columns:

   ```
   SELECT effect, foo, movie from movies
   ```
2. You can find the complete CQL3 spec [here](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql3/CQL.html).
3. You could also follow this [CQL tutorial](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/webhelp/index.html#cql/cql_using/about_cql_c.html).

Comment: In other words, there are no "column slices" in CQL3

Comment: So if I am to understand this and based on what I am reading:  CQL is the new (and preferred) method for reading column families.  Essentially what Thrift describes as a column family is essentially just a table in CQL which has two columns:  A key and a value.  Is this correct?

Comment: @Paul that's incorrect. Please go through the links in the answer here  to better understand the Thrift vs CQL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865703/difference-between-thrift-and-cql-3-columns-rows/17872321

Comment: Ok, I FINALLY have it!  Like @AlexPopescu said before, I was (in "Ghostbusters" parlance) "Crossing the Streams"  Those links helped a bunch.